# Build error related to gunicorn in Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I'm new to Google Cloud and I'm trying to deploy test web app built in Python and Flask.
I'm getting error when building app in cloud. I configured .yaml file according to Google's tutorial and I have all other required files (requirements.txt etc).

Error:

```
Step #1 - "builder": gunicorn
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: check python version
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `python version` full cmd:
Step #1 - "builder": /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 --version
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     check python version took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     uploading_requirements.txt_pkg_lyr took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     build process for FTL image took 200 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     full build took 200 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder":     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder":     exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 54, in main
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/builder.py", line 114, in Build
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 153, in BuildLayer
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/single_layer_image.py", line 60, in GetCacheKey
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 109, in GetCacheKeyRaw
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 332, in GetCacheKeyRaw
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 346, in _python_version
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
Step #1 - "builder":     errread, errwrite)
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 938, in _execute_child
Step #1 - "builder":     self.pid = os.fork()
Step #1 - "builder": OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37_app_builder:python37_20200223_3_7_6_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Comment: Please include your `cloudbuild.yaml` and/or the build command you're using as well.

Comment: well I don't have specific cloudbuild.yaml, I'm just following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app  
EDIT: my web app is not the one in tutorial, but it works locally on my machine, also i have added some stuff to app.yaml (env_variables for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)

Comment: This may have been due to a transient error, is this still failing for you?

Comment: well it is working now, but I had removed some parts of my app.
do you know if installing TensorFlow in your app to run models can cause issues?